# Create a bar plot calculating separate percentages for each facet_wrap clusters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset (df) with three variables: 
Two groups of people (A/B) perform a 3 types of tasks. The response might be correct (1) or incorrect (0).
Find attached:

```
 Group Type Response
     B    3        0
     A    1        1
     A    2        1
     B    1        0
     A    1        1
```

I have created the next bar_plot using ggplot:

```
    ggplot(df,aes(x = factor(Type), fill = factor(Response), y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_bar() +
  stat_count(geom = "text",
             aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")),
             vjust = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
  facet_wrap(~Group)
```

[image]

I would like to have separate calculation of % for each Group and Response. E.g,  the sum of the % in group A in correct responses should be 100%, and so on.
Any ideas/suggestions?

I have tried the next options, without success:

```
    ggplot(df,aes(x = factor(Type))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..density.., group= Response)) +
  stat_count(geom = "text",
             aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")),
             vjust = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
  facet_wrap(~Group)
```

error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'density' not found

```
    ggplot(df, aes(x=Type, y=Response, fill=Response)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ylab("percent") + 
  facet_wrap(~ Group)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is easier to do the percentage calculation outside of the plot. You can for instance use dplyr as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
plot_data <- group_by(df, Group) %>%
             mutate(group_size = n()) %>%
             group_by(Group, Type, Response) %>%
             summarise(perc = n()/max(group_size))
plot_data
## Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
## Groups: Group, Type [?]
## 
##    Group  Type Response      perc
##   (fctr) (int)    (int)     (dbl)
## 1      A     1        1 0.6666667
## 2      A     2        1 0.3333333
## 3      B     1        0 0.5000000
## 4      B     3        0 0.5000000
```

This first counts the number of rows per Group. The percentage needs a little trick: `summarise()` expects a single value per group, but `group_size` may be longer than that. But in that case, it is just a repetition of the same number and I can reduce the vector to a single number by taking the maximum. (I could also have used `min()` or `mean()`.)

Then, you can do a simple bar plot and add the annotations with `geom_text()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Type, fill = factor(Response), y = perc)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Group) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(perc)), vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, you example data does not lead to the plots that you showed, such that my plot looks different from yours.